# Query optimization OR slow populating ObservableObject inside DoWork in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Here's the table columns in my table:

[image]

```
EmpNo = Employee number of the creator of the row
DateReceived = the datetime when the ticket is received by employee
DateProcessed = the date the row is inserted
Workcode = ticket name
TimeStart = the datetime the ticket started
TimeEnd = the datetime the ticket ended
```

I need to get the `ElapsedTime` and `TurnAroundTime` of each transaction.

```
ElapsedTime = TimeEnd - TimeStart
TurnAroundTime = SUM (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd)) 
                WHERE EmpNo = @emp AND TimeStart BETWEEN @datereceived AND @timeend

    => in short TurnAroundTime is the sum of all the elapsedtime 
    of all the rows created by employee from datereceived to timeend
```

Here's the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT `Id`, `EmpNo`, `DateProcessed`, `Workcode`, 
`DateReceived`, `TimeStart`, `TimeEnd`, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd) ElapsedTime,
CASE
    WHEN DateReceived = '0001-01-01' OR 
         DateReceived = '0000-00-00' OR 
         DateReceived IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE get_tat(EmpNo, DateReceived, TimeEnd)
END AS TurnAroundTime
FROM table1 WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-23';
```

Here's the `get_tat()` function that is used in the query:

```
FUNCTION `get_tat`(_empno VARCHAR(6), _dateReceived DATETIME, _timeEnd DATETIME) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_return INT;

    SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd)) INTO var_return
    FROM table1 WHERE Empno = _empno AND TimeStart BETWEEN _dateReceived AND _timeEnd;

    RETURN var_return;
END$$
```

The problem is the query took 30secs+ to finish the execution. Can someone explain to me how to optimize this query?

Additionally here's an index that I set:

```
 INDEX (`EmpNo`, `DateProcessed`, `Workcode`, `TimeStart`)
```

One of my friend told me that I need to optimize the `get_tat` function, but I have no hint how can I start that. PLease help. Thanks! :)

**--EDIT--**

Optimized my code by the help of **Gordon**. From average execution time 30secs+, it's now averaging around 6-8secs. :)

Found out what's so slow in my c# code, I'm populating DataGrid in ViewModel. I'm populating ObservableCollection like this:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => _finishedTransactions.Add(x)));
```

This is called inside `DoWork()` in `ViewModel` so I can't use the simple:

```
_finishedTransactions.Add(x);
```

It throws:

```
This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
```

`_finishedTransaction` is `ObservableCollection<Class>`

I debug that part of the code and found out that this takes time:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    var x = new FinishedTransactionModel(row);
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => _finishedTransactions.Add(x)));
}
```

Comment: The query works on timestamp data for ~ a whole month. Sometimes, there is no place for tuning. You should try narrow down your DateProcessed.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic query is:

```
SELECT . . .
       (CASE WHEN DateReceived = '0001-01-01' OR 
                  DateReceived = '0000-00-00' OR 
                  DateReceived IS NULL THEN 0
              ELSE (SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd))
                    FROM table1 t2
                    WHERE t2.Empno = t1.empno AND
                          t2.TimeStart BETWEEN t1.dateReceived AND t1.timeEnd
                   )
        END) AS TurnAroundTime
FROM table1 t1
WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-23';
```

And now that I'm looking a bit closer, the index for the subquery/function should be `table1(EmpNo, TimeStart, TimeEnd)`.

For this query, you want an index on `table1(DateProcessed)`.

The query for the function is:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd)) INTO var_return
FROM table1
WHERE Empno = _empno AND TimeStart BETWEEN _dateReceived AND _timeEnd;
```

Your existing index should be correct for this.

If you don't need the function, you might find that combining these into one query (rather than using a function call) is more efficient.

EDIT:

The combined query would look like:

```
SELECT `Id`, `EmpNo`, `DateProcessed`, `Workcode`, 
       `DateReceived`, `TimeStart`, `TimeEnd`, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd) ElapsedTime,
       (CASE WHEN DateReceived = '0001-01-01' OR 
                  DateReceived = '0000-00-00' OR 
                  DateReceived IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE get_tat(EmpNo, DateReceived, TimeEnd)
        END) AS TurnAroundTime
FROM table1
WHERE DateProcessed BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-23';
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for this. I added INDEX(DateProccessed) and I combined the query and the function into single query but still the same. Average execution time is 30.04 secs. I tried to EXPLAIN each SELECT statement but with the subquery I am getting the same rows even if removing the index.

Answer (score 0):

YOu Can increase Default execution time of you script by  Set_time_limit(50); use before your query.